When controlling a motor with PWM, why is the measured current proportional to PWM Duty Cycle?
For background, I am using a DC motor controller from polulu with an integrated current sensor (shunt resistor and op-amp) driven by PWM at a fixed frequency to control a brushed DC motor with a speed reducer gearbox. The motor also has an integrated incremental encoder I am using to measure speed of the output shaft. I was planning to implement a cascaded PID where the innermost loop controls the motor current. This was done mostly as a learning exercise.
When monitoring the motor current from the current sensor, I have noticed that the current increases/decreases with Duty Cycle when the motor is in motion. However, from my understanding of PWM, it should only affect the average voltage applied to the motor. Current draw is (or should be) dependent on the load as I understand it. The speed also increases/decreases with Duty Cycle (as expected) and since this is a brushed DC motor, the speed and current draw should be inversely proportional. But my testing has shown this to not be the case. I included a plot of current vs speed below.

So, if the load (while in motion) is constant (the gearbox), then why does the measured current increase/decrease with Duty Cycle?
Specs:

12V Brushed DC Motor
217:1 Speed Reducer Gearbox
Rated Torque: 2.8kg.cm
No-Load Current: ≤ 0.15A
PWM Frequency of 1500Hz

Edit: The current is average current. I sampled the current over a period of 10 seconds at "steady state" for the selected Duty Cycle and filtered it through a moving average filter with a wide window.
Update:
I decided to open up the gearbox of one of the motors I tested and found there was a healthy application of grease, which would contribute a dynamic load on the motor proportional to speed. So from a mechanical perspective, this could contribute to the change in current when changing Duty Cycle/speed.
I additionally decided to investigate a potential electrical source for the current - Duty Cycle relationship.
I started by examining the DC motor equations. Specifically the voltage equation for a DC motor:
V = Ke * w + I * R + L * dI/dt
V for Average Source Voltage
Ke for Motor Electrical Constant
w for Motor Speed
I for Average Current
R for Motor Resistance
L for Motor Inductance
dI/dt for Current Ripple
I examined the current variable: I_load = Tau/Ke where Tau is Load Torque and Ke is Motor Electrical Constant. While it is known that the current for a DC motor is proportional to load, there should also be a different current source. Since the motor is modeled as a RL circuit with a voltage source biased against the source voltage (back EMF), the inductance and resistance of the motor would affect the current draw. The equation for average current through an RL circuit is:
I_RL = Vs/R * (1 - e^(-t/T))
I_RL for Average Current
Vs for Source Voltage
R for Resistance
t for Charging Time
T for Electrical Time Constant = L/R
As such, the new motor equation would be:
V = Ke * w + (I_load + I_RL) * R + L * dI/dt
V = Ke * w + (Tau/Ke + Vs/R * (1 - e^(-t/T))) * R + L * dI/dt
Since this is being driven by PWM, we can assume the Charging Time is the Duty Cycle ON time. As such, it is reasonable to assume that the Duty Cycle (and PWM frequency) would affect the current draw. I decided to experimentally investigate this as well.
I decided to repeat the previous experiment but instead of sweeping through Duty Cycles, I swept through PWM frequencies at a constant Duty Cycle. The reason for this is when I swept through Duty Cycles, I was also varying the speed; as such the dynamic load from the gearbox potentially dominate any electrical loads varying from Duty Cycle. By keeping the Duty Cycle constant, and varying the PWM frequency, I will be manipulating the Duty Cycle ON time for the RL circuit and thus average current without manipulating the average voltage and thus speed. At least this was my intent, but I found it was not as simple as that.
I used two different DC motors with gearboxes for this experiment. The motor used in the previous experiment and a different larger DC motor with a larger gearbox and reduction ratio rated for 12V. I included the plots below.






The first thing to note, is the non-linearity of the plots. There appears to be a more complicated relationship happening which makes this difficult to model accurately. Additionally, while the scales are different, the plots for both motors are very similar. This implies that this may be intrinsic to most DC motors, regardless of make/model.
Secondly, current absolutely changes with PWM frequency and thus Duty Cycle, but it is not a direct proportional relationship (IE non-linear). So it is reasonable to conclude that it does have an effect on the current, but not a direct one. It also appears to be potentially affecting the voltage/speed.
I can now understand why it has been suggested that the PWM is manipulating the average power to the motor. As such, the average voltage/speed and average current/torque are indirectly manipulated as a consequence but are also affected by other parts of the system. This could partially explain the non-linear response as well. So, I am now concluding that the PWM signal manipulates the average power delivered to the motor.

Unless you have a fancy dynamometer that can apply a constant torque, you don't have a constant load. The load of your gearbox is dependent on the angular speed. Higher speed, more losses.

By losses, you mean that it becomes harder to maintain high speeds for the gearbox, due to things like kinetic friction?

Yes, more friction.

I'm assuming there is an electrical component too. I've gone back and done a little math using the motor equation: I = (V - Kt*w)/R where I is current, V is applied voltage, Kt is the electrical constant, w is speed, and R is resistance. If only the voltage and speed change (proportionally), then the resultant current drawn will also change proportionally, correct?

From a purely qualitative perspective, frictional losses will increase with speed, corresponding to an effective increase in mechanical load, or torque that the motor must overcome.
Torque is loosely tied to current (and speed with voltage), and from your graph I see that current increased by a factor of only 2, while speed increased 6-fold, which to my mind sounds in keeping with a doubling of mechanical resistance.
Also, it's not clear if that current plot is average or peak current, an important consideration given the inductive nature of the motor winding, and that the only meaningful measure of performance is power, not voltage or current in isolation.

I see, that makes sense from a mechanical point of view. I always thought friction would be constant but I neglected things like kinetic friction from any lubrication/contaminants and such.
The current is average current. I sampled the current over a period of 10 seconds at "steady state" for the selected Duty Cycle and filtered it through a moving average filter with a wide window. I should have included it initially but edited it. In regards to the current/velocity plot, I thought of making a feedforward for the PID by mapping resultant current to desired speed.

I am also aware that a motor is modeled as an RL circuit with an opposing voltage source (in a simple model), so the inductor resists the increase in current. So when a PWM is applied, the cycle time of the Duty Cycle determines how much current is built up in the inductor of the motor and discharges, which can result in a triangular current waveform (as the PWM turns on and off).
I just want to know how I could model this. In the equation for DC motor voltage: V = Kt * w + I * R + L * (dI/dt), would Duty Cycle be affecting the inductive term?

Power isn't exactly proportional to duty cycle; for most DC motors, only
velocity is proportional to PWM duty cycle, when lightly loaded.
The use of a DC motor to stir a viscous liquid will make a square-of-RPMs
term, while the same motor lifting a load will have a constant retarding term.
A motor is useful in overcoming some retarding force; the nature of
that force is important.

By square-of-RPMs term, you mean that the faster you want to stir the fluid, the harder it becomes to stir it?

@BraydenScarlett Yes, the retarding force at high Reynolds number has, roughly, a square-law force versus velocity (and cube-law power versus velocity)
